# Having problems with mouse drag mesh vertex deformation in 2D

Tags: 2d, vertex

[image]

This is in 2D space. I want to create a mouse dragging mechanic like the one shown in the picture where I find a range of vertices relative to the position I first clicked where the red vertices have the most "weight" and the grey vertices have less weight. Then I move them depending on where I drag my mouse but also curve the outer side vertices so it looks more smooth.

So far I'm able to move a stack of vertices around my mouse but the outer vertices are not deforming the way I want because I want the grey outer edge vertices in front of the direction I drag to move forward and the grey vertices in the opposite direction to move inward. I'm not sure how I can differentiate the outer vertices from the inner ones.

Edit: I've tried a springs approach kindly suggested by @DMGregory but there are some issues.

1. My springs approach currently doesn't prevent any vertices from moving passed any edge it's not connected to which will ruin the topology of the mesh once that happens (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kadqu.jpg).
2. This approach runs very slow for higher vertex counts and if I were to add checks for edges then the speed would become even worse than it already is.

Code for node: https://hatebin.com/sjtgqgcvjl
Code for spring: https://hatebin.com/uzdtqersuy
Code for main script: https://hatebin.com/ekfdjkpneb

Are there better ways to approach the 1st problem?

Comment: How have you tried solving this problem so far? If you can show us your code, that can help answers match and work with what you already have. It also helps us see what kinds of data structure you're using, what kind of information each vertex might have about its neighbours, etc.

Comment: This is what I have so far https://i.imgur.com/voLH5nc.gif @DMGregory

The different colors represent different sets of vertices I'll use for deforming but its not smooth at all as you can see. Ideally I want the grey vertices at the front to move forward and the grey vertices at the back to move inward but I can't seem to figure out a way to do this.

Comment: Have you considered a "[force-directed graph](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force-directed_graph_drawing)" approach, where you simulate each vertex as a mass connected by damped springs for the edges, so the movable masses get tugged into a configuration that minimizes the stretching overall?

Comment: Sadly, experimenting and running into walls is half of game development. I know it's painful but it's often necessary. I can say that spring sims tend to give a lot of bang for their buck — very simple code, very rich outcomes. The spring network kind of transmits information from one area to another, giving you some pretty powerful emergent behaviour without hand-coding those things in as special cases. But I can't guarantee that emergent behaviour is exactly what you want it to do. It's a crude approximation of the forces that hold materials together, so it will have some similar dynamics.

Comment: Forgive me but I don't think I've explained myself properly and left out some details.
 
So when I select an inner part of the circle and move it towards the edge like so https://i.imgur.com/KdkvZGX.gif, it should push the vertices in front of the direction it moves forward and the sides should also deform as well like so https://i.imgur.com/o6n2G2i.png. 

Those outer vertices would need to recognize direction so could the springs fore-directed graph implementation deal with that? @DMGregory

Comment: The springs on the leading edge will tend to try to push the vertices on that edge out in front of the moved section, while the springs on the trailing edge will tend to try to stretch the bordering vertices to span the gap left behind, pinching them together a little from their connections to one another. Comments are not for extended discussion, so that's the last I'll say about that here.

Comment: @DMGregory Hello. I've tried the force-directed graph but it turned out to be very under-perfomant. I've been tackling this issue for weeks and still can't figure out any alternative.

Comment: Want to edit your question to show us what you tried, and in what specific way it's falling short of your goals?

Comment: @DMGregory updated